# Join on DataFrames creating CartesianProduct in Physical Plan on Spark 1.5.2

Tags: join, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, cartesian

I am running into performance issue when joining data frames created from avro files using spark-avro library.

The data frames are created from 120K avro files and the total size is around 1.5 TB.
The two data frames are very huge with billions of records.

The join for these two DataFrames runs forever.
This process runs on a yarn cluster with 300 executors with 4 executor cores and 8GB  memory.

Any insights on this join will help. I have posted the explain plan below.
I notice a CartesianProduct in the Physical Plan. I am wondering if this is causing the performance issue.

Below is the logical plan and the physical plan. ( Due to the confidential nature, I am unable to post any of the column names or the file names here )

```
  == Optimized Logical Plan ==
Limit 21
 Join Inner, [ Join Conditions ]
  Join Inner, [ Join Conditions ]
   Project [ List of columns ]
    Relation [ List of columns ] AvroRelation[ fileName1 ] -- large file - .5 billion records
   InMemoryRelation  [List of columns ], true, 10000, StorageLevel(true, true, false, true, 1), (Repartition 1, false), None
  Project [ List of Columns ]
   Relation[ List of Columns] AvroRelation[ filename2 ] -- another large file - 800 million records

== Physical Plan ==
Limit 21
 Filter (filter conditions)
  CartesianProduct
   Filter (more filter conditions)
    CartesianProduct
     Project (selecting a few columns and applying a UDF to one column)
      Scan AvroRelation[avro file][ columns in Avro File ]
     InMemoryColumnarTableScan [List of columns ], true, 10000, StorageLevel(true, true, false, true, 1), (Repartition 1, false), None)
   Project [ List of Columns ]
    Scan AvroRelation[Avro File][List of Columns]

Code Generation: true
```

The code is shown below.

val customerDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");

```
val dates = new RetailDates()
val dataStructures = new DataStructures()

// Reading CSV Format input files -- retailDates
// This DF has 75 records
val retailDatesWithSchema = sqlContext.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("delimiter", ",")
  .schema(dates.retailDatesSchema)
  .load(datesFile)
  .coalesce(1)
  .cache()

// Create UDF to convert String to Date
val dateUDF: (String => java.sql.Date) = (dateString: String) => new java.sql.Date(customerDateFormat.parse(dateString).getTime())
val stringToDateUDF = udf(dateUDF)

// Reading Avro Format Input Files
// This DF has 500 million records
val userInputDf = sqlContext.read.avro(“customerLocation")
val userDf = userInputDf.withColumn("CAL_DT", stringToDateUDF(col("CAL_DT"))).select(
                      "CAL_DT","USER_ID","USER_CNTRY_ID"
                    )

val userDimDf = sqlContext.read.avro(userDimFiles).select("USER_ID","USER_CNTRY_ID","PRIMARY_USER_ID") // This DF has 800 million records

val retailDatesWithSchemaBroadcast = sc.broadcast(retailDatesWithSchema)
val userDimDfBroadcast = sc.broadcast(userDimDf)

val userAndRetailDates = userDnaSdDf
  .join((retailDatesWithSchemaBroadcast.value).as("retailDates"),
  userDf("CAL_DT") between($"retailDates.WEEK_BEGIN_DATE", $"retailDates.WEEK_END_DATE")
  , "inner")



val userAndRetailDatesAndUserDim = userAndRetailDates
  .join((userDimDfBroadcast.value)
    .withColumnRenamed("USER_ID", "USER_DIM_USER_ID")
    .withColumnRenamed("USER_CNTRY_ID","USER_DIM_COUNTRY_ID")
    .as("userdim")
    , userAndRetailDates("USER_ID") <=> $"userdim.USER_DIM_USER_ID"
      && userAndRetailDates("USER_CNTRY_ID") <=> $"userdim.USER_DIM_COUNTRY_ID"
    , "inner")

userAndRetailDatesAndUserDim.show()
```

Thanks,
Prasad.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much here to go on (even if your data or even column / table names are confidential it could be useful to see some code which could show what your are trying to achieve) but `CartesianProduct` is definitely a problem. O(N^2) is something you really want to avoid on large datasets and in this particular case it hits all the weak spots in Spark.

Generally speaking if join is expanded to either explicit Cartesian product or equivalent operation it means that join expression is not based on equality and therefore cannot be optimized using shuffle (or broadcast + hashing) based join (`SortMergeJoin`, `HashJoin`).

**Edit**:

In your case following condition is most likely the problem:

```
userDf("CAL_DT") between(
  $"retailDates.WEEK_BEGIN_DATE",  $"retailDates.WEEK_END_DATE")
```

It would be better to compute for example `WEEK_BEGIN_DATE` on `userDf` and join directly

```
$"userDf.WEEK_BEGIN_DATE" === $"retailDates.WEEK_BEGIN_DATE"
```

Another small improvement is to parse date without using UDFs for example with `unix_timestamp` function.

**EDIT**:

Another issue here, pointed out by [rchukh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/935083/rchukh) is that `<=>` in Spark <= 1.6 is expanded to Cartesian product - [SPARK-11111](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11111)